# How to block a spam bot .htaccess proper formatting?

Tags: htaccess, web-crawlers, spam, spam-blocker

I have downloaded my access log file from my cPanel and found I have a bot I would like to stop. In the access log, there `User-Agent` string reads the following;

> 88.80.205.219 - - [08/May/2014:23:29:52 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 301 - "-" "-"
>   88.80.205.219 - - [08/May/2014:23:29:56 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 29019 "-" "-"

What is the proper format in my *.htaccess* file to block this bot only?

Comment: There is no user agent string in there

Comment: Those are complete access log entries. The `User-Agent` is just the last part ie. `"-"` (a single hyphen, which probably represents an _empty_ user agent string.)

Answer (score 4):

To block all "blank" User-Agents or User-Agents consisting of a hyphen, you could use the following in your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: can anyone explain how it works? ^-?$ what does it mean?

Comment: The first line indicates a conditional rewrite, in this case if the user-agent matches the regular expression which is blank with an optional - character. If the condition statement is true, then the rewrite rule on the next line is triggered. In this case the rewrite rule is to not rewrite the URL at all, but to return an HTTP forbidden code (403).